# Javascript D3.js unable to import stack() module

Tags: javascript, d3.js, stack

Trying to create a stacked bar chart, and I am attempting to import d3.stack() in the same way i have for other modules without any problems.

```
import { 
    select, 
    axisBottom, 
    scaleLinear, 
    axisLeft, 
    format,
    scaleBand,
    layout,
    stack,
    nest,
    max,
    schemeCategory10
} from 'd3';
```

When I try to evoke stack() using the following code an error in the browser informs me that:

```
Uncaught TypeError: stack is not a function
```

Trying to create a stack()

```
        const stack = stack()
            .y(function (d) { return d[key] })
            .values(function (d) { return d.values })
```

I have tried using d3.stack(), layout.stack(), I am using 5.16.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this one d3.layout.stack(), let me know if it worked for you

Comment: I have tried layout.stack() still the same error.

Comment: what is stack().y, in the docs i was not able to find it? can you share the docs https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/v1.3.7/README.md#stack

Comment: Good point, I cannot see it either. I plagiarised it from a YT video, heres the SC https://imgur.com/a/fZ3ueG2 if it helps put it in context.

Comment: As the screenshot says its a little old video i think it was uploaded at 2015, may be the methods changed check the version that you have and the video shows.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: If the keys are not correct in anyway this is the error that is generated.  It has nothing to do with the module not being imported correctly as the error would suggest.
Thanks to all for help.